# Microphone doesn't work on Apple Mac Book Air

Tags: microphone, apple, macbook-air

My microphone doesn't show up in Ubuntu. I am using a Apple Mac Book Air with a Realtech ALC889A chip. The sound works fin, but I just can't get the microphone to work.

I tried to modify the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file by adding different commands at the end, but it just does not want to work.

If you have any idea pleas help me. Thank you!

Comment: Is it an internal microphone, external analogue or USB?

Comment: It's an internal microphone

Comment: It should appears in the input devices.

Comment: Well that's the problem: It does not.